# Calling "Array.delete" in a helper function in a loop makes array changed each time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this very weird problem this evening when I was building something like "filter-posts-by-multiple-tags" feature.

**In the view template:**

```
<%
tags = Tag.all
selected_tags ||= nil
%>

<ul>
    <% tags.each do |tag| %>
    <% logger.info("selected_tags size:"+ selected_tags.size.inspect) %>
    <li><%= link_or_span(tag, selected_tags) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**In the TagsHelper:**

```
module TagsHelper
  def link_or_span(tag, selected_tags)
    selected_tags.delete(tag)
    link_to tag.title, tag
  end
end
```

**It outputs (in the log):**

> selected_tags size:2
>   selected_tags size:1
>   selected_tags size:0

**What I expect:**

> selected_tags size:2
>   selected_tags size:2
>   selected_tags size:2

I think var "selected_tags" in the view template should be untouched each time in the loop since it's in the different scope, isn't it?

**The ENV:**

- ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 3.1.0.rc4

Comment: Why are you using delete? delete removes the item. And it's a different scope but it's the same object.

Comment: +1 for a well-explained question that included the code, the expectation, and the reality. I wish more questions were written as well as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selected_tags.delete(tag)
```

replace to

```
selected_tags.map {|t| tag.delete(t) }
```

because I think your code will show all tag without selected_tag?it is right

Comment: Cool! I followed your advice and change `selected_tags.delete(tag)` to `selected_tags = selected_tags.map{|t| t if t == tag ? nil : t}.compact`, now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Pasted the wrong code. It should be `selected_tags = selected_tags.map{|t| t == tag ? nil : t}.compact`.

Answer (score 1):

The `selected_tags` is an instance of Array which will be passed in method by reference, so the behavior is correct.

Maybe this is what you need:

```
module TagsHelper
  def link_or_span(tag, selected_tags)
    if selected_tags.include?(tag)
      link_to tag.title, tag
    else
      # Whatever you want to do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I 1) change `selected_tags` to Integer; 2) change `selected_tags.delete(tag)` to `selected_tags += 1`. It runs just as expected - this var in the template stays untouched. Why is that?

Comment: `selected_tags.delete(tag)` modified the `selected_tags` object itself, but `selected_tags += 1` means `selected_tag = selected_tag + 1` which will assign the calculation result to `selected_tag`, not modify the original object it refs.

Comment: Well, `selected_tags += 1` is same as `selected_tag = selected_tag + 1` while `selected_tags` itself is Integer?! Call me stupid, I'm totally lost.